# Is it possible to capture output of a flink datastream to a list

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to flink and don't know whether this is correct approach or dumb thing i have a datastream of string datatype and i am trying to capture the data in datastream into a List i am trying something like below

```java
public class DataCapture {

    public static List<String> stringList(DataStream<String> dataStream) {

        List<String> myOutputlist = new ArrayList<>();

        dataStream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void flatMap(String value, Collector<List<String>> out) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("==================DATASTREAM-VALUE=====================" +value);
                myOutputlist.add(value);
                out.collect(myOutputlist);
            }
        });

        return myOutputlist;
    }

}
```

Is there way i can get this into a list i tried even adding a sink and try to capture output into list event that is also not working

Answer (score 1):

Not sure regarding production code, but in a couple of test cases I've used a `CollectSink` wrapper around `List`, similar to [this one](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/testing.html#testing-flink-jobs):

```java
// a testing sink
class CollectSink implements SinkFunction<String> {

    // must be static
    public static final List<String> values = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public synchronized void invoke(String value) throws Exception {
        values.add(value);
    }
}
```

This sink will collect elements in `value` List.
You just need to add this sink to a pipeline.

*Update*: as @kkrugler pointed, replaced the `ArrayList` with a thread-safe `CopyOnWriteArrayList` `List` implementation to be able to safely use this sink with a parallelism greater then 1.

Comment: Note that this might have issues if the sink's parallelism is > 1, as you'll have concurrent access to the ArrayList. I usually recommend using a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, which is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is for troubleshooting or testing purpose, if so you call `dataStream.executeAndCollect()` which will return list of the respective objects.